# huggingface converting dataframe to dataset

Tags: python, pandas, huggingface-transformers

I have code as below. I am converting a dataset to a dataframe and then back to dataset. I am repeating the process once with shuffled data and once with unshuffled data. When I compare data in case of shuffled data, I get false. But when I compare data in case of unshuffled data, I get True. Why is there this kind of discrepancy

```
import pandas as pd

import datasets





import numpy as np

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support

from tqdm import tqdm


import os
```

```
train_data, test_data = datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'], 

                                             cache_dir='/media/data_files/github/website_tutorials/data')

train_data_s1, test_data_s1 = datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train[0:500]', 'test[0:500]'], 

                                             cache_dir='/media/data_files/github/website_tutorials/data')

print (type (train_data_s1))

print (type (test_data_s1))
```

```
#shuffling adn taking first 500 from train_data and test_data

# Create a list in a range of 10-20

l1=[*range(0,499,1)]

  

# Print the list

print(l1)

train_data_s1_shuffled=train_data.shuffle(seed=2).select(l1)

test_data_s1_shuffled=test_data.shuffle(seed=3).select(l1)

print (type (train_data_s1_shuffled))

print (type (test_data_s1_shuffled))
```

Why do I get `False` when I compare data below? But when in the next block I get `True`?

```
from datasets import Dataset

import pandas as pd

#dataset_from_pandas = Dataset.from_pandas(df_pandas)

#https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-create-custom-classlabels/13650# "basic_sentiment holds values [-1,0,1]

from datasets import ClassLabel

x1=pd.DataFrame(train_data_s1_shuffled)

x2=Dataset.from_pandas(x1).cast_column("label", ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None))

print (x2.data==train_data_s1_shuffled.data)#returns false

print (x2.features==train_data_s1_shuffled.features)
```

#not sure why data matches in this case but not in earlier case?

```
x11=pd.DataFrame(train_data)

#print (x11.head())

x21=Dataset.from_pandas(x11).cast_column("label", ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['neg', 'pos'], names_file=None, id=None))

print (x21.data==train_data.data)#returns True

print (x21.features==train_data.features)
```

Comment: this answers it https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/dataset-to-pandas-dataframe-and-back-to-dataset/14801/2